# AlertDialog standard background color on ICS/JB

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

Does anybody know which background color is used in the standard AlertDialog on ICS/JB?

I use the SwipeListView from 47deg (https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview).
Because there are two views overlapping I have to set a background color to the front View.

If I set "background_dark" it is too dark, see screenshot:

[image]

So I need the same color as the title or the button has but I don't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just set the background of the ListView item to transparent? I would imagine the standard alertview will use the holo dark background drawable, which is a gradient.

Color of the title is #282828

Comment: If I set the "FrontView" to transparent or with no color I see both LinearLayouts overlapped.

Behind the "Test 3" you see is a second LinearLayout.
This is only visible if you swipe the "Test 3" away.

Comment: Ah .. now I see. Well the color in the header is #282828

Comment: Yes, thanks! 
Where did you find it or how did you know that?
Does a xml color or drawable exists instead of the fix one "#282828" ?
Something like android.color.background_dark?

Comment: Couldn't find it in the styles / themes files. I use this chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eye-dropper/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka) which lets me get the color from a web page :-)

Comment: Haha, really good trick :-)
Thanks again!
Can you please change your "Answer" above to the color you wrote me?